# How to get supported locals (language translations) for a given voice by talkback in Android

Tags: android, text-to-speech, talkback, google-text-to-speech, accessibilityservice

I want to display list of languages which can be spoken by talkback. When I searched I found a way to get available voices by receiving broadcast with extra **RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES**. but here I want to know for a given voice say English (USA), how many locals can be read/spoken by talkback application.

Ex - When we enable accessibility, and choose English as voice, it can read many device locals (translations), but it can't read some. So Is there a way to find out how many Locals are supported for one voice.

Answer (score 0):

TalkBack uses the installed text-to-speech (TTS) engines to produce its spoken output, e.g. Pico, rather than speak for itself.

[An introduction to Text-To-Speech in Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html) will get you started with the TTS engines, and then you need to ask the *engine* which languages it supports using `TextToSpeech.isLanguageSupported(Locale)` - see [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#isLanguageAvailable%28java.util.Locale%29).

The phone also has to support the `Locale`, so use `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` to determine that. A locale is a language, which may optionally have an associated country and variant.

To obtain the full list of supported locales, use:

```
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(context, listener);
for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
    if (tts.isLanguageSupported(locale)) {
       // spoken language supported
    }
}
```

Finally, for your example, you'll need to filter this list by language, i.e. `Locale.getLanguage()`, to determine which are English (in your case).

Comment: @sits_1608 Did you resolve your problem? I'm interested to know the result.